# org-mode - no syntax highlighting in exported HTML page

Tags: html, emacs, org-mode

I've been trying to get the syntax highlighting to work when exporting org-mode formatted file to HTML, but none of what I've done so far has worked. I followed the [Babel configuration guide](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/languages.html#configure) but the code block on the generated HTML page still looks plain. I have also set `(setq org-src-fontify-natively t)`. What am I missing?

Comment: Are you including a language in your `SRC` block header, e.g. `#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp`? Does the source block get properly highlighted in the Org buffer? Do you have `htmlize` installed?

Comment: 1) Yes, the block is demarcated, and 2) I think it's properly highlighted in the buffer. 3) `htmlize` is not yet installed.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Code block syntax highlighting in Org-mode's HTML export [depends on the `htmlize` library](http://orgmode.org/org.html#fnd-119), which Org-mode's documentation says is included but may actually need to be installed separately:

> If the example is source code from a programming language, or any other text that can be marked up by font-lock in Emacs, you can ask for the example to look like the fontified Emacs buffer¹¹⁹. This is done with the ‘`src`’ block, where you also need to specify the name of the major mode that should be used to fontify the example¹²⁰, see [Easy Templates](http://orgmode.org/org.html#Easy-Templates) for shortcuts to easily insert code blocks.
>
> ```lisp
> #+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
>   (defun org-xor (a b)
>      "Exclusive or."
>      (if a (not b) b))
> #+END_SRC
> ```
>
> ...
>
> ¹¹⁹This works automatically for the HTML back-end (it requires version 1.34 of the `htmlize.el` package, which is distributed with Org). Fontified code chunks in LaTeX can be achieved using either the listings or the [minted](http://code.google.com/p/minted) package. Refer to `org-latex-listings` documentation for details.

`htmlize.el` is available via [MELPA](http://melpa.milkbox.net/).

Comment: Also `htmlize.el` is available using aptitude in Debian Jessie in package `emacs-goodies-el` as `apt-get install emacs-goodies-el `

Comment: I don't get how to install it on Windows. It is not available in package-list-packages list...

Comment: @avp, `htmlize` isn't in the default GNU ELPA package repository. Are you using any third-party repositories (e.g. MELPA)?

Comment: @Chris: I use            ("gnu" . "http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")
           ("MELPA" . "http://melpa.org/packages/")
           ("org" . "http://orgmode.org/elpa/")
Here is my config: https://github.com/paul-alkhimov/emacs-configurations It is in org-mode, so easily readable on github.

Comment: @avp, but it's not in your list of installable packages? It [should be](http://melpa.org/#/htmlize). Maybe you need to run `package-refresh-contents`?